# Elephant ear plant a bit limp and discolored

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, plant-recommendations

I bought this elephant ear a few days ago and wanted an opinion on the outter leaves. Are they dying and a lost cause, or do I maybe need to change conditions? The soil was dry when I bought it, so I've watered it once since getting it last Sunday. It's by the window but getting pretty indirect light. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Katie, welcome! Would you please [edit] your post and add a photo of your plant? And as for all new users, I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through our [help] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: Elephant ears love water ; you can't water it too much. They are invasive in my pond.